# How do I keep my script streaming so, it doesn't disconnecting?

Tags: twitter

So, I'm using filtered stream. Unfortunately, every time I turn it on, after 5 minutes its turns off but during that time, it catches tweets.
What I'm trying to do is keep it on 24/7 so, it doesn't turn off after 5 minutes. Also, if it disconnects I want it so, it tries connecting again.

This is the code sample I'm using to help adjust my code:

- https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.js

```js
function streamTweets(retryAttempt) {
  const stream = needle.get(streamURL, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`
    },
    retryAttempt: 20000
  });

  stream.on('data', (data) => {
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(data)
      console.log(json.data.text)
      retryAttempt = 0;
    } catch (e) {

      if (data.detail === "This stream is currently at the maximum allowed connection limit.") {
        console.log(data.detail)
        process.exit(1)
      } else {
        // Keep alive signal received. Do nothing.
      }
    }
  }).on('err', error => {
    if (error.code !== 'ECONNRESET') {
      console.log(error.code);
      process.exit(1);
    } else {
      // This reconnection logic will attempt to reconnect when a disconnection is detected.
      // To avoid rate limits, this logic implements exponential backoff, so the wait time
      // will increase if the client cannot reconnect to the stream. 
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.warn("A connection error occurred. Reconnecting...")
        streamTweets(++retryAttempt);
      }, 2 ** retryAttempt)

    }
  });

  return stream;
}

(async() => {
  let currentRules;

  try {
    //get all stream rules
    currentRules = await getRules();

    //delete all stream rules
    await deleteRules(currentRules);

    //Set rules based on array above
    await setRules();

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  streamTweets(0);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to send the keepalive in your header?

Also, I changed the authorization header to match the syntax that of your linked GitHub code source.

```js
function streamTweets(retryAttempt) {
  const stream = needle.get(streamURL, {
    headers: {
      "authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
      "Connection": "keep-alive"
    },
    retryAttempt: 20000
  });
```

Also, according to the [Twitter docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/quick-start): " If you would like to close your connection, you can press Control-C in your command line tool on either Mac or Windows systems to break the connection, or you can also close the window. "

Are you sure it's not disconnecting because you closed the terminal session, or was closed by something like an ssh timeout?

Comment: I'm sure that I'm not disconnecting the terminal session, I'll try the keep alive header right now

Comment: yeah its not working, unfortunately. Is there any other possible scenarios that could affect it?